# Automatically create handler signature in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Working in c#, asp.net 4.0, VS2015, I've created a user control which is just a dropdown list with a couple of other properties that the user can pass to it, as well as an event and delegate.  When the dropdown is changed, the OnSelectedIndexChanged is triggered, which then checks if the event is populated and calls the delegate.

The definition look like this:

```
public partial class SiteList : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public event SiteIDChangedHandler SiteIDChanged;
    public delegate void SiteIDChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
}
```

The problem I'm having is when that user control is consumed, and the event is attached, the definition of the delegate is not created in Visual Studio when working in the .aspx page.  For example as I'm typing the following

```
<CW:SiteList runat="server" ID="SiteList" OnSiteIDChanged=""
```

and hit the = sign for OnSiteIDChanged, it then says "Create New Event" as an option for OnSiteIDChanged, just like any other event I've used in .net.  When I selected "CreateNewEvent", the method which is created in the code behind is:

```
 protected void SiteList_SiteIDChanged()
    {
    }
```

and doesn't contain the proper signature of the handler.

Now what's strange is if I bind the event in the code behind with this:
    SiteList.SiteIDChanged +=

It says "Press (TAB) to insert" and the method which is inserted is:

```
private void SiteList_SiteIDChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

So what am I missing so that the proper method signature is created with the sender and eventargs is automatically in the first instance?  I know it can be done, all of the .net controls do it!

Comment: You should use the built-in `EventHandler` delegate instead of creating your own.

Comment: ASPX web forms doesn't work like the Win Forms designer, you can't do that.

Instead do it server side in the OnInit Override.  SiteList.SiteIDChange += (tab here for auto complete).

Worth noting that not many people use Web Forms anymore for new dev, it's a lot nicer (imo) to use MVC 5+ and Web Api 2.

Comment: It does work that way in webforms.  Go ahead and create an asp:dropdownlist and try it.  It works.  Our entire org is webforms.

Comment: Which version of visual studio?  I've never been able to get auto complete to work from the designer.

Comment: 2015, 2013, 2012.  Always works.  Note this isn't from 'design' view, but source view.

Comment: Hmm, I'll see if I can get a test to work.

Comment: Ok, so I stand corrected, it does work, see my results in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work using the same name as your control in visual studio.

Here is my control code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace TestWebFormsAutoComplete
{
    public class SiteList : System.Web.UI.UserControl, IPostBackEventHandler
    {
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> SiteIDChanged;

        public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
        {
            int i = 0;
        }

        protected virtual void OnSiteIDChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (SiteIDChanged != null)
                SiteIDChanged(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my web.config control/namespace entries:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="TestWebFormsAutoComplete"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />      
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="test" namespace="TestWebFormsAutoComplete" assembly="TestWebFormsAutoComplete"/>
      </controls>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="TestWebFormsAutoComplete"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

And here is my test aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestWebFormsAutoComplete._default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Test Site List <test:SiteList OnSiteIDChanged="Unnamed_SiteIDChanged" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In my test, when I filled out the SiteList OnSiteIDChanged event, I got a drop with the option to "Create New Event", I chose that, and it created this for me,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TestWebFormsAutoComplete
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Unnamed_SiteIDChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Note, I do not have an ASCX based front end for my user control, it's in code only.  So I am not using a tag prefix with a src attribute.  I suspect that's why it doesn't work for you.

While this does seem to work with Code based controls, I do not think it will work with source based ASCX user controls.

However you can still make a UserControl with no ASCX front end.  You can use "Page.LoadControl" etc to load src markup into your control from someplace else.

Comment: Also note that when writing controls in the same website you are developing in, you can run into caching issues in visual studio often, requiring a clean and rebuild, even a site app pool recycle in some cases, to get the aspx code editor to see the changes.

Comment: Not sure I understand your last statement, as code in an ASCX isn't "source based", it's compiled, just like any other class file.

Comment: ASCX user controls have a front end markup, if you are using the default template.  The code behind is compiled, sure, but with the front end ASCX markup it won't get any of it's child controls.  You can make c# class that inherits from UserControl and is 100% code based, but it can also have an ASCX markup front end that is rendered by the ASPX engine, or via Page.LoadControl.